# How to change a field's name in a table using linq to sql?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

So i have been learning Linq to SQL recently and I got it to query out record, but for the like of me, I couldn't figure out how to change the table's field. I really appreciate your help guys:

```
 using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var ns = from nod in db.Nodes
                         where nod.Name == "MFMN"
                         select nod;
                int pop = db.Nodes.Count();
                foreach (var n in ns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(n.NodeID + " " + n.lkpNodeType + " " + n.Name + " " + n.DeploymentID);

                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by changing table's field ? do you want to use a different name/alias for your existing Fields, for example for `NodeID`, do you need `ID` ?

Comment: Precisely, like modify the field from NodeID to something like identification. Can I do that using linq instead of sql studio management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) like:

```
var ns = from nod in db.Nodes
            where nod.Name == "MFMN"
            select new 
            {
                Identification = nod.NodeID, 
                //all other fields
            };
```

and then:

```
foreach (var n in ns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n.Identification..... //rest of the fields

}
```

But, you have to specify all your fields that you need in your code. It is also useful when you only want to select specific columns and not all of the columns.

Comment: so I have to list other fields in the table too? I cant just modify one? Also, do I need to do db.submitOnChange() or the field's name will b change automatically?

Comment: If you need multiple properties to be mapped, you can use Automapper.

Comment: @Rozen, Yes, you have to specify other fields as well, You can specify their name only and no alias. For your second part of question, `db.SubmitChanges` will not change the field name in table. Your query is only projecting results in an anonymous type, it is not changing anything on the database

Comment: so this is like giving the field an alias, and the actual table fields' name couldnt be changed at all? Excepting manually do that in the database using sql?

Comment: @Rozen, Yes, that is correct, or you can change it through your C# code, executing `sp_rename`, but then you will be required to create / refresh your dbml as well.